# ImageView not shown

Tags: android

in my project, ImageView containing an image is not shown.
Th
Here's the code:

XML:

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/viewtab"
    android:layout_width="359dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp" />
```

Java:

```
Vtab = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewtab);
Vtab.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The imageview has no image set in it

Comment: have you set any image in your ImageView, or post some more code

Comment: provide your full code because when you define imageview not set any image.

Comment: set image in imageview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your image in your XML file

```
android:src="@drawable/image"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this .. image put into drawable folder.

```
Vtab.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background); // define your image.
```